# How do I correctly handle exceptions within 'use' block?

Tags: kotlin

I want a `Closeable` resource to auto-close itself, but at same time I want to be able to handle any possible exception.

Consider the following piece of code.

```
val opcPackage: OPCPackage

URI.create(document.fileUrl).toURL().openStream().use {
    opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(it)  // it = InputStream!
}
```

In case of exception, the InputStream will auto-close itself thanks to the `use` block. However, the execution flow will be interrupted.

I still want to handle such exception and *do something* with my program (e.g. log, send a signal ecc...)

The following does not compile:

```
kotlin.runCatching {
    URI.create(document.fileUrl).toURL().openStream().use {
        opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(it)
    }
}.onFailure { 
    // e.g. log and exit
}
```

This one kind of defeats the whole purpose of `use` since I have to manually close the `Closeable`.

```
URI.create(document.fileUrl).toURL().openStream().use {
    try {
        opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(it)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        // ...
        it.close()
        return internalServerError()
    }
}
```

At this point, I might as well simply use

```
val inputStream = URI.create(document.fileUrl).toURL().openStream()

try {
    opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(inputStream)
    inputStream.close()
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    inputStream.close()
    return internalServerError()
}
```

but I'm trying to use kotlin features properly.

What's the best snippet for this use-case?

Comment: Who says if you handle the exception in `use` you’ve to close the resource manually?

Comment: What compiler error do you get with `kotlin.runCatching`?

Comment: Why does the `runCatching` variant not compile? What error are you getting? It *should* compile.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar yeah fair, it also hit me a few seconds ago. However, even by removing the manual-close, the code doesn't seem quite right. Joffrey's answer below (first snippet) looks more appropriate.

Comment: Please provide a bit more info about the enclosing function, because it's hard to see what you're doing with this variable mutation and the `return` statement in the middle of those expressions. A more idiomatic Kotlin approach would be to use expressions to initialize your variable instead

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha the code does not compile because `Captured values initialization is forbidden due to possible reassignment`. Changing `val opcPackage` to `var opcPackage` would solve it, but it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: @MarkoPacak then you should fix this by using `use` as an expression instead of assigning the value inside the lambda

Comment: @MarkoPacak I see, all these functional utils such as `runCatching` expects you to use them as expressions so you could assign the return value inline.

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha correct, inline assignment fixes this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`use()` allows you to deal with the resource management in one expression, even in case of exception. You can still `try-catch` around it:

```kotlin
val opcPackage = try {
    URI.create(document.fileUrl).toURL().openStream().use {
        OPCPackage.open(it)
    }
} catch (e: SomeException) { 
    // e.g. log and exit
    // no need to manually close here
    // you do need to break control flow here or provide a default OPCPackage
}
```

Your variant with `runCatching` is actually fine too, you just may need to use it as an expression to initialize your variable:

```kotlin
val opcPackageResult = runCatching {
    URI.create(document.fileUrl).toURL().openStream().use {
       OPCPackage.open(it)
    }
}.onFailure { 
    // e.g. log and exit
}

// you still need to handle the Result type later
```

But even if you catch the exception inside, the end of the `use()` block will still close the resource for you:

```kotlin
val opcPackage = URI.create(document.fileUrl).toURL().openStream().use {
    try {
        OPCPackage.open(it)
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        return internalServerError()
    }
}
```

Or you can use a plain `try-catch-finally` as well:

```kotlin
val inputStream = URI.create(document.fileUrl).toURL().openStream()

val opcPackage = try {
    OPCPackage.open(inputStream)
} catch (ex: Exception) {
    return internalServerError()
} finally {
    inputStream.close()
}
```

Comment: I think your first snippet is what I'm looking for. It combines assignment,  resource auto-closing and exception handling all in a couple of lines

Comment: I added a variant with `runCatching` as well, if you really want to use the functional approach. but I don't see a huge improvement over the `try-catch` here to be honest :)

Comment: @MarkoPacak also, whatever your choice, I would personally extract any of these expression snippets into a function in real life. It's usually ugly to leave that low-level handling in the middle of higher-level code, but what you extract depends on how you want to deal with the `return`.

Comment: I'm OK with the first snippet thx. It's easy enough to read

Comment: As @Joffrey said usage of monadic/functional style `runCatching` could be overkill  if code is designed in a classic try/catch style. But it has many advantages. Btw, take note that the `runCatching` doesn't return `OPCPackage` type, it returns a `Result` which contains an `OPCPackage`.

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha good points. I fixed the `runCatching` example to avoid the confusion about the return value.